# Activating a dart app with pub global activate

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I created a new Dart app like this:

```sh
dart create hello
```

I can run the app like this:

```sh
dart run hello/bin/hello.dart
```

I try to activate the app like this:

```sh
dart pub global activate --source path hello
```

But I can't run the file like I would expect:

```sh
hello
```

> zsh: command not found: hello

The `.pub-cache/bin` folder is in my cache but pub global activate didn't put it there.

This does work:

```sh
dart pub global run hello
```

> Hello world!

But I'd like to be able to run the script without typing `dart pub global run` every time.

If I do a package from pub.dev it works ok:

```sh
dart pub global activate webdev
```

It puts a webdev executable inside the `.pub-cache/bin` folder and I can run it.

```sh
webdev --version
```

> 2.7.4

So is there another step I need to do to make my hello app get into the executable folder?

I also tried compiling it:

```sh
dart compile exe hello/bin/hello.dart
```

And activating it again:

```sh
dart pub global activate --source path hello
```

But there is still no binary in the `.pub-cache/bin` folder. Any suggestions?

### Update

After getting Kevin's answer below, I added the following to pubspec.yaml:

```
executables:
  hello:
```

Then I ran the following command:

```sh
dart pub global activate --source path hello
```

which gave the following result (username modified):

```
Resolving dependencies... 
Got dependencies!
Package hello is currently active at path "/Users/suragch/Dev/DartProjects/hello".
Installed executable hello.
Activated hello 1.0.0 at path "/Users/suragch/Dev/DartProjects/hello".
```

But if I run this:

```sh
hello
```

I get the following error:

```
/Users/suragch/.pub-cache/bin/hello: line 7: pub: command not found
```

Running this still works, though:

```
dart pub global run hello
```

> Hello world!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So it looks like this problem was caused because because of a bug as a result of switching from `pub` to `dart pub`. If you open the `.pub-cache/bin/hello` file with an editor, you'll see the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
# This file was created by pub v2.13.1.
# Package: hello
# Version: 1.0.0
# Executable: hello
# Script: hello
pub global run hello:hello "$@"
```

The error about line 7 is the last line where you can see it is referencing plain `pub`. Change that line to the following:

```
dart pub global run hello:hello "$@"
```

Now you can run your app from anywhere:

```sh
hello
```

> Hello world!

This is only a temporary workaround. Follow [this issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/42530) for updates. Thank you to Kelvin Omereshone for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Could you help me? I try’s  to get this file, but when I try to open it doesn't get me te right file. How to get there and open it? open file:///Users/myuser/.pub-cache/bin/dswitch doesn't work

Comment: @chrisu.chrisu, I'm not sure either.

Answer (score 2):

You need to list the files under `bin/` that you want to be executable in the `executables` section in `pubspec.yaml` file. For example for `bin/hello.dart` to be executable add the following to `pubspec.yaml`

```yaml
....
executables:
  hello:

....
```

Then when you run: `dart pub global activate --source path hello`

You can now call `hello` in `bin/` without running: `pub global run hello`

Again

You have to list every executables you intend to be made available to the user of your package in the CLI under the `executables` key in `pubspec.yaml`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That brought me closer to a solution. I didn't know about the executables section of the pubspec.yaml file before. However, I'm still getting an error (see my question update).

Comment: Can you run `echo $PATH` and confirm that `/Users/<user>/.pub-cache/bin` is in your path?

Comment: Also I did a quick search and I think you might find an answer here: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/42530

Normally with your flutter environment and Dart environment all updated, the solution I gave should work out of the box.

Comment: Yes, it is all fixed now. Although your answer pointed me in the right direction it didn't quite solve my problem. I added another answer below that showed my final solution. However, your answer definitely deserved my upvote and the bounty. Thank you again!