# Downgrade dart version

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to downgrade dart version from 2.13.4 to 2.13.0 or lower.
How to make it from terminal I tried some solution but it doesn't work in my case.

```
dart pub install 2.13.0
```

then dart --version and still I have 2.13.4

Comment: What OS are you using?  Are you trying to downgrade a standalone Dart SDK installation or the Dart SDK that is bundled with Flutter?

Comment: MacOS, yes because I can't use mobx plugin, it is needed 2.13.0 version as a maximum version. I tried flutter pub run build_runner build with erors

Comment: Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on macOS 12.3 21E230 darwin-x64, locale en-PL)

Comment: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.13.

Comment: You can't downgrade the Dart SDK installed with Flutter without downgrading your Flutter SDK too.  Go to your Flutter SDK directory and run `git checkout` to an earlier Flutter SDK version.

Comment: Also, [mobx's `pubspec.yaml`](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx.dart/blob/master/mobx/pubspec.yaml) says that its maximum supported Dart SDK version is 3.0.0, not 2.13.0.  Where and how are you getting that error message?

Comment: Hi @chrisu.chrisu, i have add another answer that works also for mac: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71503150/16241837

Comment: @chrisu.chrisu Could you please answer my previous question?

Comment: I get this error where I use flutter pub run build_runner build, error occurs in terminal in Android Studio. It is about analyzer 2.8.0

flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/analyzer-2.8.0/lib/source/line.dart:1:1: Error: THe specified language version is too high.

Comment: it is weird, because I override analyzer to lower version but heh it loads 2.8.0 IDK why

Answer (score 2):

1. Run this Command: `flutter downgrade`
2. Close and open Android Studio again.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

For the flutter sdk use the fvm package, for the dart sdk use switch.

DSwitch:
https://onepub.dev/packages/dswitch

FVM:
https://onepub.dev/packages/fvm

Comment: % dswitch                         
/Users/myuser/.pub-cache/bin/dswitch: line 7: pub: command not found, I can't find this  file and open it. Could you help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67750537/activating-a-dart-app-with-pub-global-activate

Comment: @chrisu.chrisu have a look at dcli and the dcli manual for writing cli scripts.  https://dcli.noojee.dev/

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/dswitch https://pub.dev/packages/fvm

Answer (score 0):

This Solution works only if you use Windows and Android Studio.

**Step 1**

For download an older flutter Sdk go to this link: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases and download an older flutter Sdk.

---

**Step 2**

After you done that search in the bottom left Search Bar from Windows (edit system environment variables) and open the first option

then click on the bottom right Button: (Environment variables...)

then select the (path) in you (user variables for flutter) and edit the old Path to the new Path from the older flutter Sdk

---

**Step 3**

Go in you Android Studio and go to (File > Settings... > Languages & Frameworks > Flutter) and change the Path of your current flutter Sdk to the new flutter sdk Path that has an older version of Flutter in.

The (Dart SDK path) will change automatically if you click Apply

---

After you done that close and open Android Studio again. Now you have an older dart Sdk version.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have macos can you help? :)

Answer (score 0):

In terminal:

flutter downgrade

Comment: I get this. I'm a total noob. Ideas? "16:31 $ flutter downgrade
There is no previously recorded version for channel "master"."